# Simple camera correction

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

Currently I do my camera calibration using the checkerboard image and by using following OpenCV functions:

```
cvFindChessboardCorners();
cvFindCornerSubPix();
cvCalibrateCamera2(...,intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs,NULL,NULL,CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO);
```

Then the resulting intrinsic_matrix and distortion_coeffs are applied to the camera image:

```
initUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic,distortion,cv::Mat(),                                      
                        getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(intrinsic,distortion,...),...);
warpPerspective()
```

This works smoothly here. But now I want to do a more simple calibration where only a linear trapezoidal (means spatial) distortion and perhaps a rotation of the camera has to be corrected. Nonlinear distortions caused by the cameras optics can be ignored.

So in principle only camera rotation values around X, Y and Z mounting angle need to be corrected. Any idea how this can be done? Do I have to calculate my own intrinsic_matrix and distortion_coeffs in order to apply them to the functions above or are there other functions in OpenCV to correct such distortions?